# Excel VBA for opening a file with changing in the file name every month

Tags: vba, excel

I want a VBA code to open a file which name is changing every month

```
ChDir "S:\Credit_Risk\MIS\Consolidated Customer profile Macro\Securities"

Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "S:\Credit_Risk\MIS\Consolidated Customer profile Macro\Securities\Enterprise  pending cases as at end of Oct.2016.xls"
```

Any one can help

Answer (score 3):

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
"S:\Credit_Risk\MIS\Consolidated Customer profile Macro\Securities\Enterprise  pending cases as at end of " & Format(Date, "MMM.YYYY") & ".xls"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you place your file in a sub-directory which only contains your file you can open it with :

```
ChDir "S:\Credit_Risk\MIS\Consolidated Customer profile Macro\Securities\myFile\"
myFiles= Dir("*.*")
While myFiles<> ""
Workbooks.Open myFiles
```

Comment: i have 5 files to open in the same location with changing in the names, so how can i open them all without making debug with out referring to the full name

Comment: Can you place these 5 files in 5 sub-directories and replace them at each change of name? So whatever the names they have your program will read always the same places.